# Highcharts tooltip backgroundColor inherit from the hovered element

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Its possible to add backgroundColor to the tooltip as the hovered line?

For example when hover on blue the tooltip backgroundColor to be blue

```
    tooltip: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
            borderRadius: 0,
            shadow: false,
            useHTML: true,
            percentageDecimals: 2,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
            formatter: function () {
                return '<div class="tooltop">'+this.point.name + '<br />' + '<b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y).replace(",", " ") + ' Kč [' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2) + '%]</b></div>';
            }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/style/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `mouseOver` event of a series to change the fill color of the tooltip.

See this code demonstration:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        events: {
            mouseOver: function(event) {
                $(".highcharts-tooltip > path:last").attr("fill", this.color);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xquLnon4/) of it in action.

Answer (score 1):

You can set useHTML as true, disable paddings and add style param in your div. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/50pvg4b3/

```
tooltip: {
            useHTML:true,
            style:{
                padding:0
            },
            formatter: function () {
                return '<div class="tooltip" style="background-color:'+this.series.color+';">'+this.point.name + '<br />' + '<b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y).replace(",", " ") + ' Kč [' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2) + '%]</b></div>';
            }
        },
```